# "no libName in java.library.path" on System.loadLibrary("libName")

Tags: scala, apache-spark, anaconda, jupyter, apache-toree

Working in an anaconda jupyter notebook, within an Apache Toree - Scala kernel.

I'm calling : `System.loadLibrary("libName")` and I get a java error saying `no libName in java.library.path` while when I check the env I see `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/lib/folder`, with `folder` containing `libName.so`. I also called `System.getProperty("java.library.path")` to check directly the java var, and it contains `/path/to/lib/folder` too.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong ?

I get the env to have this variable set modifying the `jupyter_notebook_config.py`, using the two following python lines :

`os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = "/path/to/lib/folder"
c.Spawner.env.update('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')`

Answer (score 0):

Fix found. Put the `libName.so` within  `[...]/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/toree/lib`. Then `System.loadLibrary("libName")` will work.